# Date conversion in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display dates (range of dates). The format of dates coming from DB seperated by hyphen is

> Sep 21, 2017 - Sep 29, 2017

I want to convert it to the format

> 09/21/2017 - 09/25/2017

How can I convert this?

Comment: Have a look at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: The two dates are coming in a single field from Db seperated by a hyphen.

Comment: Please post your code so far and detail exactly what isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use this function that converts to your format:**
[Your CodeSand](https://codesandbox.io/embed/solitary-pond-jeynj)

```js
const convert = dateRange =>
    dateRange.split(" - ")
        .map(date => new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(new Date(date)))
        .join(" - ")

console.log(convert("Sep 21, 2017 - Sep 29, 2017"));
```

**The code below works and uses only pure JavaScript ES6.**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Intl.DateTimeFormat` object.

```js
const dbDate = new Date("Sep 21, 2017")

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(dbDate))
```

From the MDN Docs -

> The Intl.DateTimeFormat object is a constructor for objects that
>   enable language-sensitive date and time formatting.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat

**Edit** - If you are getting both dates in an single string you can `split()` it out and then apply the above method and concatenate (based on your requirement).

Comment: never knew about `Intl`, +1

Comment: JS is so vaaaaaast :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]ReactJS have it's own date library which is [moment date library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment). It can Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates and times in JavaScript.

So use npm to install react-moment along with its peer dependency, moment by running this command :

> npm install moment

Then Import and use in your Typescript file

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
const date = moment("Sep 21, 2017").format('MM/DD/YYYY');
console.log(date); // 09/21/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js mentioned in your comments has helped me a lot with the situation, specifically for what you want to do is found [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

And moment.js package for reactjs can be installed from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment)

this will definitely help with your formating issue

Answer (score 0):

```
const date = "Sep 21, 2017 - Sep 29, 2017"


const dateConvertor = date => {


    const splited = date.split(" ")

    const dateItems = []
    splited.forEach((item,index) => {
            if(item.indexOf(",") === -1) {
                dateItems.push(item)
            } else {
                dateItems.push(item.slice(0,item.indexOf(",")))
            }
     })

     let convertedDate = "";

     dateItems.forEach((item,index) => {
        if(index === 1 || index === 5) {
            convertedDate += "/"+item+"/"
        } else if (index === 3) {
            convertedDate += " "+ item + " "
        } else {
            convertedDate += item
        }
    })

    return convertedDate
}


dateConvertor(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

First separate the string so that you can use it:

```
const [from, to] = '09/21/2017 - 09/25/2017'.split(' - ');
```

This will give you 2 strings, not formatted as you want so you will need to do some further transformation (assuming momentjs is available):

```
const [from, to] = '09/21/2017 - 09/25/2017'.split(' - ').map(item => 
moment(item).format('DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

If a slight format difference is OK, you might not need moment and use it like this

```
const [from, to] = '09/21/2017 - 09/25/2017'.split(' - ').map(item => 
new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(new Date(item), {month: "2-digit", day: "2-digit"}));
```

NOTE: I am using 2-digit param here, which is supposed to provide the date / month as mentioned (09 instead of 9) but there seems to be an issue with that at least in some browsers.

Some explanation if not obvious:
The split part, creates an array. The map part, will transform the 2 strings to formatted date objects. The first part (left of the =) is destructuring the array and giving you the variables to use.